# Rails Query on dynamic property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a small quiz test app, that allows each user to take multiple quizes and then gives a score on 10 for each quiz.

So a user `has_many :quizes`

And each quiz has a score on 10, the user also can see their average score, which is dynamically calculated each time the user makes the request. This is done through a method on the user model

```
def avg_score
  self.quizes.pluck(:score).sum/self.quizes.count
end
```

For the home screen of the app I want to then display all the users that have an average score of above 8.

Is there anyway I can query this dynamic value?
Or is it a better approach to create a field in the users table and then update the value each time a quiz is completed?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can query this dynamic value? Or is it a better approach to create a field in the users table and then update the value each time a quiz is completed?

Yes it's possible if you are using ActiveRecord with a SQL database. You can use `group by` in SQL to group each quiz by the user ID, then `avg` to return the avg score, then `where` to limit the list to users that have more than 8 avg score.

```sql
SELECT user_id, AVG(score)
FROM quizzes
WHERE AVG(score) > 8
GROUP BY user_id
```

In Rails that should be something like this:

```rb
Quiz.select(
  :user_id,
  Quiz.arel_table[:score].sum
).where(
  Quiz.arel_table[:score].sum.gt(8)
).group(:user_id)
```

Comment: A few notes: 1) SUM != AVG (you can change this to `Quiz.arel_table[:score].average`. 2) you cannot use an aggregate function in a WHERE clause we would need to move this to HAVING e.g. `.having(Quiz.arel_table[:score].sum.gt(8))` 3) this returns `Quiz` objects whereas I believe the OP is looking for `User` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the database to handle this process entirely.

First: Sum/Count = Average so `quizes.average(:score)` would be a better implementation here

That being said if you want all the users with an average score over 8 we should not perform this operation on an instance by instance basis instead lets put this in the model and execute a query to return these users e.g.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quizes 
  scope :over_score_of, ->(score) { 
    select(User.arel_attribute(Arel.star),
           Quiz.arel_attribute(:score).average.as('average_score'))
           .joins(:quizes)
           .group(:id)
           .having(Quiz.arel_attribute(:score).average.gt(score))
  } 
end
```

Then you can use this throughout the application as

```
@users = User.over_score_of(8)
```

and you can access the average score for each user in the virtual attribute `average_score` without needing to execute an additional query.

The SQL generated will be akin to

```
SELECT 
  "users".*,
  AVG("quizes"."score") AS average_score
FROM 
  "users" 
  INNER JOIN "quizes" ON "quizes"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
GROUP BY 
  "users"."id" 
HAVING 
   AVG("quizes"."score") > 8
```

**Notes:**

- Some Databases (MSSQL for instance) do not support grouping by just the primary key so some implementation changes may be required
- Depending on the data type of score the "average" may return as a whole integer even though you many want a decimal value (casting would be required)

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers already, for completeness and just because I'm not hard in love with Arel (has poor readability imo) you can consider using plain old SQL fragments.

```
    User.select("users.*", "avg(quizzes.score) as average_score",
       .joins(:quizzes)
       .group('users.id')
       .having("avg(quizzes.score) > ?", 8))
```

I think it's easy enough that you don't have to introduce Arel - its closer to the actual sql query and thus more readable imo; the drawback is you have to reference the tables and in theory write sql fragments that are not portable, but again this to me seems simple enough.